# Get categories by title descendant

Tags: categories, loop

I'm displaying my post category by the following:

```
<?php   
foreach (get_categories() as $cat) :?>

<div class="post animation-element bounce-up cf" <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<div class="row subject ">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12 ">
<a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>">
<img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" />  </a> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My category display by title ascendant this way, but I am looking to display them by title descendant.

Answer (score 0):

If only you could use `get_categories()` reference in the Codex, you could see that this function supports arguments.

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'orderby' => 'name', // default value, can omit it
    'order'   => 'DESC'
));

foreach($categories as $cat) {
    // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Hi Max,

Thanks, I'e try your code but it still display in ASC unfortunately :( any idea :( ? Really appreciate your time

Comment: That's impossible. Have you emptied all caches?